# Thread abort exception in C# using threads with delegates

Tags: c#, delegates, threadabortexception

I am using a thread to call a function containing a while loop to read a weights. In the while loop, I am calling a delegate function to update values in a text box.

On clicking a button named `Stop`, I am trying to abort the thread, but I am getting a Thread Abort exception:

```
 private System.Threading.Thread comm1;
 comm1 = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(reading));
 comm1.Start();

 public void reading()
 {
   while(continus)
   {
     textBox1.Invoke(
                     new PrintValueTextDelegate(PrintValueText), 
                     new object[] { text Box, value.ToString() });

     for (int i = 0; i < risposta.Length; i++)
     {
        risposta[i] = 0;
     }

     if (_protocollo.Manda_TLC1(2, 0x70, risposta) == true)
     {
        if ((risposta[0] & 0x80) != 0x80)
        {
           cella = risposta[1] * 256 + risposta[2];
           string rt = cella.ToString();
        }
      }
   }
 }

 private void btnstop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   try
   {
      continus = false;             
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);               
      comm1.abort(); // wait for close foreground thread 
   }
   catch (Exception rt)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(rt.ToString());
   }          
 }
```

For the above code I am getting thread abort exception can any one please help me out with this problem.

Comment: help me out... **why** are you trying to call thread.abort? that is quite a deadly method... is there something specific you are *trying to do* here? (the "what" rather than the "how")

Comment: Thread.Abort() throws that exception by design, there is no way around it other than hiding it with a try-catch block

Comment: i am trying to read the weight continually from the thread and displaying the weight in text box. when the calibration of weight is over i am trying to close it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
comm1.abort();// wait for close foreground thread
```

to

```
comm1.join();// wait for close foreground thread
```

`abort` halts the thread immediately, whereas `join` waits for it to finish.

Comment: but when i try to read the weight again from that . on press  read button i am getting "Error opening com1 :ioexception"

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a thread abort exception because you are telling the thread to abort...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx (whcih isn't working for me at the moment but I grabbed text from google's cache) says:

> The exception that is thrown when a call is made to the Abort method.

Note that this is not an exception telling you that your call to Thread.Abort() has failed, it is an exception from the thread you are aborting saying "Argh! I've just been aborted!".

If you want to stop more gracefully then make your stop call change your `continus` variable in your while loop to false. Then the while loop will stop running and your thread should finish.

Comment: thank u chris for your valuable suggestion . now it is working

Answer (score 2):

Calling `Thread.Abort()` throws a thread abort exception, that is how it works.

See the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.abort.aspx) "Raises a ThreadAbortException in the thread on which it is invoked"

Answer (score 2):

Use CancellationTokenSource to issue a cancel operation to a thread. Note that your application must check if cancellation has been requested.
Use thread.Join to wait for a thread to exit.